# Copy Metadata from Entities to ViewModels in Automapper 5

Tags: model-view-controller, automapper, viewmodel, modelmetadataprovider

In my MVC application I use Autofac IoC container together with Automapper. It gives me an opportunity to implement custom ViewModels.

The main question: How can I copy Metadata from Entities to ViewModels using Automapper 5.1.1?

I tried to implement [Bettys](http://bzbetty.blogspot.com/2012/06/using-automapper-to-copy-metadata-from.html) solution, but I can't correctly register new providers [using this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26866002/6441494).

Code is also presented below:

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MetadataProvider(
AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ValidatorProvider(
AutoMapper.Mapper.Engine.ConfigurationProvider);
```

or

```
ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new MetadataProvider(
(AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider)AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration);

ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(new ValidatorProvider(
(AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider)AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration));
```

There is no property like Mapper.Engine.

When I implement a second approach, I got invalid operation exception:

> Additional information: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with
>   appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances
>   through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls
>   to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or
>   UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the
>   appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

So, how should I initialize AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration?

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Or maybe there is another, better way to map metadata with viewmodels?